# Multiprocess server UDP socket goes slower than single process?

Tags: c, sockets, process, fork

I've written 2 server programs to read multiple client messages and send them back using sockets via UDP; the 2 server programs differ from the management of the receiving and sending messages back; the first one simply takes the message and sends it back, the second one receives the message and creates another process to send the message back. The client sends 10000 messages to the server and I noticed that the first one resends more messages than the second one, a lot more, like 100:1;

Here's the code for the server with only one process:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define BUFLEN 512
#define NPACK 10
#define PORT 3000

void diep(char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in si_me, si_other;
    int s, i, slen=sizeof(si_other);
    char buf[BUFLEN], buf_to_send_back[BUFLEN];

    if ((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP))==-1)
        diep("socket");
    memset((char *) &si_me, 0, sizeof(si_me));
    si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_me.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (bind(s, &si_me, sizeof(si_me))==-1)
        diep("bind");

    while(1)
    {
        //receive message
        if (recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, &si_other, &slen)==-1)
        {
            diep("recvfrom()");
        } else 
        {
            //create buffer to send it back
            sprintf(buf_to_send_back, "Hi %s:%d,\nyour packet has this content: %s\n", inet_ntoa(si_other.sin_addr), ntohs(si_other.sin_port), buf);
            //send a message back
            if (sendto(s, buf_to_send_back, BUFLEN, 0, &si_other, slen)==-1)
            {
                diep("sendto()");
            } else
            {
                printf("Response sent\n");
            }
        }
    }
        close(s);
        return 0;
}
```

And here the code I used in the second server, the one with 2 process, one to receive and one to send back:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BUFLEN 512
#define NPACK 10
#define PORT 3000

void diep(char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in si_me, si_other;
    int s, i = 0, slen = sizeof(si_other);
    char buf[BUFLEN], buf_to_send_back[BUFLEN];
    pid_t pid;


    if ((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP))==-1)
        diep("socket");
    memset((char *) &si_me, 0, sizeof(si_me));
    si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_me.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (bind(s, &si_me, sizeof(si_me))==-1)
        diep("bind");


    while(1)
    {
        if (recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, &si_other, &slen)!=-1)
        {
            pid = fork();
            if (pid == 0)
            {
                //create buffer to send it back
                sprintf(buf_to_send_back, "Hi %s:%d,\nyour packet has this content: %s\n", inet_ntoa(si_other.sin_addr), ntohs(si_other.sin_port), buf);
                //send a message back
                if (sendto(s, buf_to_send_back, BUFLEN, 0, &si_other, slen)==-1)
                {
                    diep("sendto()");
                } else
                {
                    printf("Response sent\n");
                }
            } else if(pid > 0)
            {
                printf("a message arrived\n");
            }
        }
    }

    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

The client program I used with both is this:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFLEN 512
#define NPACK 10
#define PORT 3000
#define SERVER_IP "127.0.0.1"

void diep(char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in si_other;
    int s, i, slen=sizeof(si_other);
    char buf[BUFLEN];

    if ((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP))==-1)
        diep("socket");

    memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
    si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_other.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    if (inet_aton(SERVER_IP, &si_other.sin_addr) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "inet_aton() failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(1)
    {
        printf("\nInsert a message to send:\n");
        scanf("%s", buf);
        for(i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            if (sendto(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, &si_other, slen)==-1)
            {
                diep("sendto()");
            } else
            {
                printf("Message sent:\n %s\n", buf);
            }
        }
        if (recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, &si_other, &slen)==-1)
        {
                diep("recvfrom()");
        } else {
            printf("A message has been received:\n %s\n", buf);
        }



    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: There is extra latency introduced by creating a new process. Firstly, for the actual work required to create the process and then the lag between when the process is created and when it actually gets scheduled by the OS. It doesn't really make sense to pay the cost of spawning a new process just to send a single message.

Comment: Why? Creating a whole process to send one UDP datagram is a major waste and misuse of resources. Simple answer: don't.

Comment: No wonder it is so much faster. As Harry noticed in his answer, you keep making more processes. After you have launched about 2 per CPU core you should be a maximum system utilization. Actually a pretty good technique with UDP if you don't care about the ordering of the packets, since any process using the socket can pull a packet in any order.

Comment: Ah guess I didn't understand when I read it at first. I thought you said the multiprocess one was faster. It *would* be if it didn't create a new process every single time.

Comment: Create the socket, bind it, then use a loop to fork() about 16 of them and try that. And make sure each child `break`s out of the loop or you'll have almost 256 of them instead of 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong. You've added the fork() in an infinite loop. I doubt this is what you want because you're not calling exit in the child and you're not reaping the children in the parent ie you are likely going to run out of file descriptors on the machine you're using.

If you want to exit the child on every received message you'll need to wait on the child or you will have a lot of zombie processes use this

```
int status;
waitpid( -1, &status, WNOHANG);
```

in the parent so it reaps the child and you don't run out of resources. You should also check to make sure that fork actually worked to see if you ran out of resources ie if **if(pid < 0)** you have an error.

If you fix the code and it's still slow and you know the code is correct then I'd look at process creation time. You can pass file descriptors to the child process which is what a lot of HTTP servers do ie Apache etc, this avoids the process creation overhead. Note. process creation is very cheap, using a good benchmarking tool would likely tell you exactly where the time is going.

Comment: I wanted to "recreate" the behavior of servers: they listen on port 80, as soon as I client request something on port 80 they create a process to respond to the client and leave the port 80 free to listen for new requests. I don't know if what I did is similar to it... Should I fork after recvfrom?

Comment: Each child has a copy of what the parent had. This means they can also listen and accept connections on the socket. Have a look on Google for pre-forking server examples in C.